# set value of $key as a new variable in foreach loop

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555057/variable-variables)

once I have established the first empty input field I then want to give it the value of `$_POST['email'];` by making the value of $key into a variable but how can I make the value of a variable into a new variable (if you see what I mean) I will try to demonstrate what I mean below:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
      foreach( $_POST as $key=> $for ) {
               if($for=="") { 

        //     $ + the value of ($key) = $email;           
                  break;
                }
         }

email: <input name="email">

    a: <input type="text" name="a" value='<?php echo $a; ?>'>
    b: <input type="text" name="b" value='<?php echo $b; ?>'>
    c: <input type="text" name="c" value='<?php echo $c; ?>'>
       <input type="submit">
```

Comment: Exactly as you described it: `$$key`. They're called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple I feel foolish. Thanks very much, now I know

Comment: Why not just stick with the `$_POST` array with its keys? Variable variables pollute the current scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$$key = $email` into the foreach, it'll make a new variable with the variable `$key` value and assign `$email` value to it.

Comment: thank you, can't believe how simple it was!

Comment: Can't believe It just so simple. thanks a lot..

Comment: Anyone knows the node js equivalent of this?

Comment: @AnishAnsari closest I could find was this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593101/javascript-server-sided-dynamic-variable-names