# Meaning of "this" in node.js modules and functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a JavaScript file which is loaded by `require`.

```
// loaded by require()

var a = this; // "this" is an empty object
this.anObject = {name:"An object"};

var aFunction = function() {
    var innerThis = this; // "this" is node global object
};

aFunction();

(function(anyParameter){
    console.log(anyParameter.anObject);
})(
    this // "this" is same having anObject. Not "global"
);
```

My question is: `this` in var `a = this;` is an empty object whereas `this` statements in functions are shadows of node.js global object. I know `this` keyword is different in functions but I could not understand why first `this` is not equal to global and `this` in functions equals to global.

How does node.js inject `global` to `this` in function scopes, and why it does not inject it to the module scope?

Comment: The value of `this` is determined as a core feature of the JavaScript language itself (although NodeJS may set the value via the language features of JavaScript). You might need to read up on some [`this` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). Note that the docs generally assume the JS is running in a browser, so the "global object" will be `window` instead of the NodeJS global object, but the concepts are the same. Some more relevant docs are [NodeJS's `this` docs](http://howtonode.org/what-is-this).

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword).

Comment: I know why two `this` values are different. My question is why and how node.js injects `global` to `this` in function scope, not to outer scope. It can inject `global` to both `this`'es keeping them different.

Comment: How do you call `aFunction`?

Comment: @ajp15243 Document you pointed gave much more insight about `this`, thanks. As I understood `this` becomes different according to where function is called. But still I could not find out why and how node.js injects `global` in different ways. Note: I have added call for `aFunction` like when I debugged.

Comment: @GökçerGökdal: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19850472/2359560) at least partially answers your question.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Here's a few fundamental facts you must understand to clarify the situation:

- In the top-level code in a Node module, `this` is equivalent to `module.exports`. That's the empty object you see.
- When you use `this` inside of a function, the value of `this` is determined anew before *each and every execution* of the function, and its value is [determined by *how* the function is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370851/understanding-javascript-scope-with-var-that-this/12371105#12371105). This means that two invocations of the exact same function object could have different `this` values if the invocation mechanisms are different (e.g. `aFunction()` vs. `aFunction.call(newThis)` vs. `emitter.addEventListener("someEvent", aFunction);`, etc.) In your case, `aFunction()` in non-strict mode runs the function with `this` set to the global object.
- When JavaScript files are `require`d as Node modules, the Node engine runs the module code inside of a wrapper function. That module-wrapping function is invoked with a `this` set to `module.exports`. (Recall, above, a function may be run with an abitrary `this` value.)

Thus, you get different `this` values because each `this` resides inside a different function: the first is inside of the Node-created module-wrapper function and the second is inside of `aFunction`.

Comment: I think I also found the code where module.export comes. In module.js (node.js source) execution code uses javascript `apply` method as `return compiledWrapper.apply(self.exports, args);`. Thanks a lot to everybody for all your helps.

Answer (score 44):

To understand this, you need to understand that Node.js actually wraps your module code in to a function, like this

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    var test = function(){
        console.log('From test: '  + this);
    };
    console.log(this);
    test();
});
```

Detailed explanation can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955050/1903116).

---

Now, this wrapped function is [actually invoked like this](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/lib/module.js#L462)

```
var args = [self.exports, require, self, filename, dirname];
return compiledWrapper.apply(self.exports, args);
```

**So, `this`, at the module level, is actually the `exports` object.**

You can confirm that like this

```
console.log(this, this === module.exports);
// {} true
```

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that `test` could be called in different ways, setting `this` to something else

Comment: From what I understand calling a function like `fn()` will make `this` point to the global object, or null when using `use strict`, it doesn't matter what the current `this` is... is Node different from the browser when it comes to setting `this`? I think the correct answer is just that the global object is set to `exports`

Comment: Care to comment on my comment (and my answer?), I think your answer is misleading because the value of this where test() is being called doesn't affect the value of this inside test(), it's all about how it's called. I'd love to understand if I'm missing something

Answer (score 17):

### Summary:

In Javascript the value of `this` is determined **when a function is called**. Not when a function is created. In nodeJS in the outermost scope of a module the value of `this` is the current `module.exports` object. When a function is called as a property of an object the value of this changes to the object it was called. You can remember this simply by the **left-of-the-dot** rule:

> When a function is called you can determine the value of `this` by looking at the place of the function invocation. The object left of the dot is the value of `this`. If there is no object left of the dot the value of `this` is the `module.exports` object (`window` in browsers).

**caveats:**

- This rule does not apply for `es2015` arrow function which don't have their own binding of `this`.
- The functions `call`, `apply`, and `bind` can bend the rules regarding the `this` value.

### Example (NodeJS):

```
console.log(this);  // {} , this === module.exports which is an empty object for now

module.exports.foo = 5;

console.log(this);  // { foo:5 }

let obj = {
    func1: function () { console.log(this); },
    func2: () => { console.log(this); }
}

obj.func1();  // obj is left of the dot, so this is obj
obj.func2();  // arrow function don't have their own this
              // binding, so this is module.exports, which is{ foo:5 }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: when i run `module.exports  = {a:4}console.log(this)` I get an empty object

Answer (score -1):

It's because the default global object in a Node.js module is the `exports` object, and you are calling `test()` which doesn't specify `this`. In traditional JS, `this` points to the global object, with `use strict`, `this` will be null.

`this` can point to anything, it just depends on how you call it.

- `test()`: Uses the global object (`exports`) as `this`, unless in strict mode, where `this` will be null;
- `test.call({})` or `test.apply({})`: You are specifying what to use as `this` (the first parameter)
- `var obj = {testRef: test}; obj.testRef()`: `this` is set to the left of the `.`, that is, `obj`

---

**Countering [thefourtheye's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30894970/227299)**

It is true that `this` in the top level of the module is `exports`, but that doesn't necessarily mean that `this` inside `test()` will also point to same thing as where it was called from.

---

**Attempting to prove that `this` and the global object both point to `exports`**

```
 myGLobal = 5;
 this.myGlobal; // 5
```

Comment: Sorry for correcting you, but `this` points to `global` in [REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) mode only

Comment: `global object in Node.js is the exports object` - It is not correct. Each and every module will have its own `exports` object.

Comment: @Curious Thanks, that's why I asked, I ran my test from the command line

Comment: @thefourtheye I did gather that from the documentation, does that mean that there are no globals? In my example above, would myGlobal not exist in a different module?

Comment: @JuanMendes globals do exist in Node, but unlike client-side JS, you should access `global` object. For example, `global.myName = 'Mike';` will be seen in all modules via `global.myName` or just `myName`. But `var myName = 'Mike';` or `myName = 'Mike'` is only seen in current module. Take a look at the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global)

Comment: @JuanMendes you pointed that because of the 'use strict', 'this' will be null when we invoke the function 'test'. In Node.js, by default, the 'use strict' mode is on?

Comment: In non-strict mode, `this` is _not_ `null` in a function invoked without a calling context. It is `undefined`.