# Javascript "apply" function seems not working for global "this"?

Tags: javascript, scope, window, this, global

I tested the scope of 'this' keyword, in nodejs:

```
color = 'red';
var o = {
    color: 'blue'
};

function say() {
    console.log(this.color);
};
say.apply(this);  //'undefined'
say.apply(global);//'red'
```

In browser:

```
color = 'red';
var o = {
    color: 'blue'
};

function say() {
    alert(this.color);
};
say.apply(this);  //'undefined'
say.apply(window);//'red'
```

```js
var color = 'red';
function say() {
  alert(this.color);
}
say.apply(this);   //'red'
say.apply(window); //'red'
```

The result is a bit weird to me: as long as "this" is a pointer to "global" or "window", why say.apply(this) will output 'undefined'?

Thanks.

Comment: Then you're not in the global scope or in any scope where `this` is not `window`. The `o` object isn't used in either example. If you run that code in the global scope, you'll get `'red'` both times. In NodeJS, if you're in a module, then you're not in the global scope.

Comment: If you run the browser code as global code, you'll get "red" for both calls to *say*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your `this` is really underfined, because `color = 'red';` has this equivalent: `global.color = 'red';`. To make it related with `this` you need to do it by yourself: `this.color = 'red';`

To get value of color from `o` object you need to write something like this:

`say.apply(o);`

This is the good example of using `apply()`:

```
function printArgs() {
  var join = [].join; // copy link of array.join into variable

  // call join with "this=arguments",
  // this call is equivalent with "arguments.join(':')"
  // here we have guarantee that method 'join()' was called from 'arguments'
  // (not from other object)
  var argStr = join.apply(arguments, [':']);

  console.log( argStr ); // output will looks like '1:2:3'
}

printArgs(1, 2, 3);
```

Also you can find useful information here:

- [Meaning of "this" in node.js modules and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770299/meaning-of-this-in-node-js-modules-and-functions)
- [What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)
- [Javascript call() & apply() vs bind()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455009/javascript-call-apply-vs-bind)