# Does nodejs global variable bind to "module" functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, this, global

It's said that nodejs, when executing a js file, will bind `this` to module context when calling function with global scope, like this:

```
function father(){
    this.id=10
}
father();
console.log(module.id);
```

It actually prints ".", not "10" as I expected. If module is the keyword to visit, I did try this:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  father();
  console.log(module.id);
})()
```

But this time, it throws out an exception in the line of `console.log(module.id)`, saying

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

Finally, I tried this:

```
console.log(this===module);
console.log(this===global);
function f1(){console.log(this===module);}
function f2(){console.log(this===global);}

function g1(){
    return function(){console.log(this===module);};
}
function g2(){
    return function(){console.log(this===global);};
}
f1();
f2();
g1()();
g2()();
```

Well it prints:

```
false
false
false
true
false
true
```

Not the same as 1st answer suggested. So I wonder how can I use "module" keyword inside a js file, that's executed by Nodejs?

And last try:

```
function h(){this.a='abc';}
h()
console.log(module.exports.a);
```

I expect to print "abc", but still it prints "undefined"

Thanks.

Comment: That IIFE doesn't make any sense at all. The `module` parameter is obviously `undefined` if you pass nothing in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's said that nodejs, when executing a js file, will bind "this" to module context

<s>Yes</s> [No](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22770299/1048572), it's bound to `exports`. If you put

```
console.log(this === module.exports); // or just `exports`
```

inside your file, it will log `true`.

> when calling function with global scope

No. The `this` value in the module scope has nothing to do with functions or how they are called. In sloppy mode, the `this` value in a function that is called plainly will be the global object, but that's not the same as the `module` object.

```
function father() {
    console.log(this === global);
}
father(); // true
```

Comment: Seems still doesn't work, see my updated post above. console.log(this === module); prints a "false" in my test.

Comment: Ooops, I thought the thing you had read was right. Where is exactly was it said? See my update.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but still [ function h(){this.a='abc';}
 h()
 console.log(module.exports.a);] will print "undefined". See my last update. Why modules.exports doesn't get updated by h()?

Comment: Because `module.exports` is not the global object. `this` in a function scope (inside `h`) is something very different than the `this` in the module scope (outside `h`).