# What is the context of functions in file by nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

What is the context of functions in files by nodejs?
If I need exports function I just write

```
module.exports = function () {};
or
module.someFunction = function () {};
```

But what context has function without module?

```
function someFunction () {};
console.log(module); // not someFunction
console.log(module.exports); // not someFunction
```

P.S. Where can I see some list of declared functions in this file? In browser I have `window`. In nodejs I have `global`, `module`, `module.exports`, but not one of its haven't the declared functions.

Comment: It has no `context` like `window` in browser!

Comment: What do you mean by _"and then turn to it"_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what context has function without module?

Same as normal JavaScript functions. In strict mode, context will be `undefined`

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  console.log(this === undefined);
})();
// true
```

and in sloppy mode (non-strict mode) global object.

```
(function() {
  console.log(this === global);
})();
// true
```

---

**Note:** If you are wondering what `this`refers to, in the module level, it will be the `exports` object. Detailed explanation can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30894970/1903116).

Comment: What do you mean by "turn to it"?