# This value of arrow function used as function expression or object's method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, arrow-functions

Another topic on `arrow functions` and this value but I can't find the answer to the code that confuses me.

When I run this code in the browser's console the result is true:

```
var f = () => { return this; };
f() === window;                // true
f()                            // Window
```

But when I run the same code in Node I get different result:

```
var f = () => { return this; };
console.log(f() === global);    // false
console.log(f() === undefined); // false
console.log(f());               // {}
```

Also when an object is defined:

```
let button = {
    isClicked: false,
    click: () => { this.isClicked = true }
}

console.log(button.isClicked);   // false
button.click();
console.log(button.isClicked);   // false
```

When this line is executed in Node the result is undefined:

```
console.log(global.isClicked);   // undefined
```

But when executed in browser, the result is true:

```
console.log(window.isClicked);    // true
```

Why when the code is executed in the browser this refers to window object but when executed in Node this does not refer to global ?

Comment: [See this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770299/meaning-of-this-in-node-js-modules-and-functions) In a Node module, at  the outer level, `this` refers to `module.exports`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I run the same code in Node I get different result:

Right. Code in Node is not run at global scope, it's run in a scope created for the Node "module" where `this` doesn't refer to the global object, it refers to the exports for the module (aka `module.exports`). More on Node modules [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

> Also when an object is defined

`this` doesn't take on a different meaning within an object initializer. Your example code:

```
let button = {
    isClicked: false,
    click: () => { this.isClicked = true }
};
```

...is doing exactly what this code does:

```
let button = {
    isClicked: false
};
button.click = () => { this.isClicked = true };
```

In both cases, the `click` function closes over `this` as it is where we're creating `button`. `this` doesn't change meaning in the initializer, but that code assumes it does (specifically, the code assumes `this` becomes a reference to the object being created, which it doesn't; in fact, there's [no way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10766107/157247) to refer to the object being created from within the initializer).

(The simplest solution in that particular case would be to use `button` instead of `this`, since the function also closes over `button`.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just recalled module.exports is an empty object , so that explains the object literal I got as a result. But I find it confusing that ordinary functions' this refers to the global object and arrow functions' this refers to the module.exports object when AF is used as function expression.

Comment: @pollx: It's because arrow functions *close over* `this`. So if `this` refers to the exports object when you create an arrow function, `this` within the arrow function refers to the exports object. Closing over `this` (and `arguments` and `super`) instead of having their own versions of those is the key feature of arrow functions. In contrast, a non-arrow function gets its `this` set by how it's called, and in loose mode, if you call it directly (not via an object property or `.call` or similar), the `this` it gets is a reference to the global object.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! What I'm missing actually is understanding of Node and its global objects (browser's as well): "Outside functions (in the top-level scope): _this_ refers to the global object in browsers and to a module’s exports in Node.js". Then "Arrow functions do not have their own _this_ value and they remember the value of the _this_ parameter at the time of their definition ".

Comment: Continues: The close over you say I understand as closure and since AF have _lexical this_ , that _this_ inherits module.exports. Then "In functions: _this_ is an extra, often implicit, parameter. In real functions, the value of _this_ depends on the mode one is in. Sloppy mode: _this_ refers to the global object (window in browsers)". Now in the button example it seems that I'm exporting 'isClicked' variable ... which is crazy.

Comment: @pollx: On a browser you would be, yes; and yes, it *is* crazy, which is part of why we have strict mode. Strict mode fixes some of the worst of the craziness of JavaScript, which (let's remember) was originally created in a period of 10 days in May 1995. Making `this` refer to the global object when you call a function directly was one of the biggest mistakes. Another (the biggest, in my view) was assigning to an undeclared identifier, which creates a global variable. Both are fixed in strict mode.