# node js behaviour for this keyword

Tags: node.js

Let's have a look to this very basic program.js:

```
console.log(this);
```

Here is the output:

```
$ nodejs program.js 
{}
```

Now, if i do the samething in the repl console:

```
$ nodejs 
> console.log(this)
```

I see a log of things at undefined at the end.

Why do we not get the same result ?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure how you are getting  an empty object or undefined  outside of a defined object this will refer to the global object.  IE.  this === global

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing two different behaviors because you're basically executing code in two different environments.

In program.js, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22771432/8173777) applies. You're in a node.js module, so `this` is the same as `module.exports`.

In the node.js repl, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/8173777) applies. You're not in a node.js module; you're in the repl which uses the global context. `this` is the same as `global`. If you executed the same code in-browser, it'd reference the `window` object instead of `global`.