# Importing IIFE with parameters in es6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to `import` the [mule uploader](https://github.com/cinely/mule-uploader/blob/master/src/mule-uploader.js) package in `es6`, but the source file uses an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) that expects the `window` scope to be passed as a parameter.

What is the correct `es6` syntax for importing the package and passing in the correct parameters to the `IIFE`?

Note: the problem with `import { mule_upload } from 'mule-uploader` isn't that the code isn't there or being executed.  The problem is the correct `scope` or `namespace` is not being passed in with the `IIFE` runs.

App.jsx

```
import { mule_upload } from 'mule-uploader'
// this runs the mule-uploader file with the IIFE
// since `this` is not `window` at this point,
// the mule-uploader object has the incorrect scope/namespace
console.log(this) // undefined

// ... react logic
componentDidMount() {
  // define settings
  // this won't work because the namespace is undefined
  mule_upload(settings)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried npm install?

Comment: @Rajesh, Yes, I'm importing after `npm install --save mule-uploader`

Comment: May you post an [mcve] showing the issue?

Comment: Any module that you create is wrapped inside an IIFE to prevent bleeding. You can check debug version of your bundle as well. Try `import * as Mule from '...'` or `import Mule from '...'`

Comment: @Rajesh, Yes, I know, I just don't know how to pass in an argument to an IIFE while importing it in `es6`.  Tried both, doesn't work.

Comment: You dont have to. If it is expecting an arg, it must have an exposed method to set it. As for `window`, it is passed as a default arg by bundler to your module in non-strict mode. I guess you are looking in the wrong area. Rather share the error you are getting

Comment: @Rajesh The error I'm getting is a console.log message from this logic: https://github.com/cinely/mule-uploader/blob/b052b62627cea8ce116c699247a7d328ccb7661b/dist/mule-uploader.js#L105.

Comment: Depends on your loader but the problem is not the IIFE it is that the IIFE takes `(this`)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I pass in the correct parameters to the IIFE?

You cannot. An IIFE does not take any arguments - it already *was* called.

> What is the correct es6 syntax for importing the package?

I don't think it's possible to import *that file* as a module, neither in ES5 nor in ES6. In modules, [`this` is not the global object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22770299/1048572). That code won't work.

You might want to issue a feature request for having the library available as an importable module (that actually exports something), instead of a script that defines a global variable. For backcompat, you can suggest them to use the UMD pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> An IIFE does not take any arguments

False ! Since the correct ES6 syntax of an IIFE is :

```
 (() => {
 }());
```

You can use arguments that way :

```
  ((param) => {
      console.log(`My IIFE + ${param} !`);
  })("myParam");
  // it will return => My IIFE + myParam !
```

or simply :

```
  (param => console.log(`My IIFE + ${param} !`))("myParam");
```

if you only have one argument...

Comment: In this way you coded it up it does _technically_ take in an argument but you'd have to hardcode it wherever you are declaring the expression itself, which doesn't help. So while you're technically correct in this answer, @Bergi's answer is also correct and is much more applicable and helpful.