# this manipulation in JS

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code which I can't understand why it prints `undefined`.
I was expecting to see "oops, global" because the call to `foo` is not from the object so it must be from the global scope which means that the `this` refers to the global `this`.

Where am I wrong?

```
var obj1 = {
    a123: 2,
    foo: function() {
        // console.log(this); obj1 is not in this. why?
        console.log(this.a123);
    }
};

var a123 = "oops, global";
var f = obj1.foo;
f(); // prints undefined. why? should have printed "oops, global"
```

I'm running the code in IntelliJ using `nodejs`.

Comment: I know and I'm not in strict mode so why it's not the global `this`?

Comment: Running in Intellij using Nodejs

Comment: Well, not I'm totally confused..

Comment: Or change `this` to `obj1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a little confusing in Node because you are dealing with two different scopes from the beginning.

Node has a `global` object. Variables assigned without `var`, `let`, `const` will be assigned to this object. When you start a process, however, there is also a module-level scope. Variables assigned with `var`, `let`, `const` live in this scope. This is an important feature that keeps variables from different modules from clashing.

In you example, when you run `f()`, `this` points to `global`. But your variable `a123` is not defined on global. You can assign it explicitly and you will see the behavior your expect with:

```
global.a123 = "oops, global"
```

This is the same as assigning without `var`, etc.

Outside of a function `this` refers to `module.exports`. For example:

```
module.exports.foo = 'bar'
console.log(this) // >> { foo: 'bar' }
```

Comment: then you are saying that `this` in nodejs is undefined outside of all functions?

Comment: also, how do I run my js file with js interpreter and not with nodejs interpreter inside the webstorm?

Comment: @StavAlfi I edited the answer regarding `this` outside functions. I'm not sure about Webstorm, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Because in node js this means module.export if you are in outer scope. In browser this means window. This is the difference.

See this 
[Meaning of "this" in node.js modules and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770299/meaning-of-this-in-node-js-modules-and-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Else, if you want to access the obj1 from this, you have to remove the local declaration.

for example, instead of

```
var obj1 = {};
```

you could use

```
obj1 = {} //it will add obj1 to this scope (window scope)
```