# Can a function modify 'this' object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Following MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

If not in strict mode 'this' in a function will point to the global object.

However When trying to modify global variable in a function it does not work as I imagined. Is there some explanation to this or a spec one can refer to?

```js
// this.somevariable = 'this is in global var'; // will not be in Global
somevariable = 'this is in global var'; // will make it to global


function something() {
    somebar = 'foo'; // this will not change the global variable
    this.somebar = 'foo'; // this will not change the global variable
    console.log(this.somevariable);
}

something();

console.log( this.somebar ); // somebar undefined
```

P.S I am just trying to figure out how 'this' keyword works. I understand that modifying global variables is a bad idea as well as not using strict mode.

*Running in node v10.14

Comment: Did you mean "somebar" and "somevariable" to be the same in your post?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of "this" in node.js modules and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770299/meaning-of-this-in-node-js-modules-and-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function is not [boxed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript), `this` is a global in sloppy mode and `undefined` in strict mode inside a function.

`this` refers to module object (`module.exports`) in Node.js module scope.

The difference is that `this` refers to a module here:

```
console.log(this.somebar); // this === module.exports
```

And refers to a global here:

```
console.log(this.somevariable); // this === global
```

Answer (score -1):

i think this example can explain you all:

```
// in node
function somethingNode() {
    console.log(global === this);
}

// in Browser
function somethingBrowser() {
    console.log(window === this);
}

somethingNode(); // true
somethingBrowser(); // true
```

in your last string you refer to `module.exports` object that's why it's not equal