# Why my function is not able to access the global object in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

When executing this function in the browser I get a correct and expected message

```js
function displayInformation() {
  console.log("student with " + this.rollNo + " is " + this.name + " who is in class: " + this.class + " and he is of " + this.subject + " stream ")
};

var student1 = {
  rollNo: 100,
  name: "Rajiv",
  class: 10,
  subject: "PCMC",
  display: displayInformation
};

var student2 = {
  rollNo: 101,
  name: "Sam",
  class: 11,
  subject: "PCMB",
  display: displayInformation
};

var student3 = {
  rollNo: 102,
  name: "Ghanshyam",
  class: 12,
  subject: "commerce",
  display: displayInformation
};

student1.display();
student2.display();
student3.display();

this.name = "Raju";
this.age = 28;
this.rollNo = 103;
this.class= 123;
this.subject = "Arts";

displayInformation();
```

However when executing this code in Nodejs I am getting `undefined` in the last sentence:

```
student with 100 is Rajiv who is in class: 10 and he is of PCMC stream
student with 101 is Sam who is in class: 11 and he is of PCMB stream
student with 102 is Ghanshyam who is in class: 12 and he is of commerce stream
student with undefined is undefined who is in class: undefined and he is of undefined stream
```

Why is the result not the same in Nodejs and the Browser?

Comment: Please post your code with code formatting, the quotation formatting has wrapped all the lines and destroyed the indentation.

Comment: Paste your code, then use `Ctl-k` to mark it as code.

Comment: You don't have add `>` before every line. Paste your code, select it, click on the `{ }` icon. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I create a stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: I get `student with 103 is Raju who is in class: undefined and he is of Artsstream` in Chrome. You never assigned to `this.class`, so it's undefined.

Comment: I am sorry as i am new to stackoverflow, i will keep make sure this doesn't happens next time. but when i run the same code in VS code i am getting undefined for all the values, also after updating the value for class.

Comment: How are you running this? From the console, or from a separate J's file?

Comment: In firefox console this code works fine.

Comment: It looks like he is running it in Nodejs, I just tested it and I am getting undefined too. I edited the question and added the node.js tag

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) post. You can convert displayInformation to an arrow function and it will work as you want it to.

Comment: You can also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770299/meaning-of-this-in-node-js-modules-and-functions) post. It is specific for Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line actual result is:

```
student with 103 is Raju who is in class: undefined and he is of Arts stream
```

The `undefined` is because you didn't assign a value to `this.class`

```js
function displayInformation() {
  console.log("student with " + this.rollNo + " is " + this.name + " who is in class: " + this.class + " and he is of " + this.subject + " stream ")
};

this.name = "Raju";
this.age = 28;
this.rollNo = 103;
this.subject = "Arts";
this.class = 123; // <-- You missed this

displayInformation();
```

Also I really recommend to not use the `this` global object, I am not sure why are you using it.

Comment: when i run the same code in VS code i am getting undefined for all the values in the terminal, also after updating the value for class

Comment: Are you executing nodejs? or just a browser javascript file?

Comment: I just executed it in Nodejs and you are right, I am getting undefined in the terminal, if you let me I can edit your question.