# Explain use of 'this' inside a function that calls an object method in Javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to process some json and write pieces of data to a few files.

So I have a function to create folder/files based on the json data and some literals. The filenames are defined by an object containing different categories:

```
const folders = {
    category1: {
        fileName: 'default',
        path : '/path',
        subpath : () => `/subpath/${this.fileName}${this.uniqueId}`
    }
}
```

This is where half of you will jump ahead and tell me that arrow functions can't see `this` of their own objects etc. I know that and that's intentional, since I'll be getting the necessary data later on.

The main function follows this pattern:

```
function readSave() {
    //suppose readFileSync would return a string 'filename' and an int 1029

    this.fileName = 'filename'; 
    this.uniqueId = 1029;

    let filePath = folders.category1.path + folders.category1.subpath();

    // I'd go on to write stuff to that file but for now let's just return
    return filePath;
}

readSave() 
// returns '/path/subpath/undefinedundefined'
// expected '/path/subpath/filename1029'
```

I also know that I *could* just pass `fileName` and `uniqueId` as args but that's not the point. This post is not exactly an attempt to find a solution but to understand why it's not working.

The confusion here is the use of `this` inside `readSave`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call) `this` inside a regular function is the same object where the function is called. Since I'm calling it on a plain js file on node, it's `global`.

All good for now. If I inspect the run inside the function call, `this` is `global` and the properties are set without problems.

*The problem is* `folders.category1.subpath()` evaluates to `undefined`.

The debugger shows when it goes to evaluate `() => /subpath/${this.fileName}${this.uniqueId}`, `this` is not `global` anymore, instead it's an empty Object. [This doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions) makes me think that the arrow function should inherit the `this` of the scope it's being called, which is `readSave`, which means `this` should be `global`.

To increase my confusion, setting the properties outside the function works flawlessly:

```
function readSave2() {
   let filePath = folders.category1.path + folders.category1.subpath();
   return filePath;
}

this.fileName = 'filename'; 
this.uniqueId = 1029;

readSave() 
// returns '/path/subpath/filename1029'
```

Inspecting the code above, everything is pretty much the same up until when it goes to evaluate `() => /subpath/${this.fileName}${this.uniqueId}`. Now the previously empty Object has two properties as they were set.

Finally, this also works exactly the same as the previous example:

```
const readSave3 = () => {
    this.fileName = 'filename'; 
    this.uniqueId = 1029;
    let filePath = folders.category1.path + folders.category1.subpath();
    return filePath;
}
```

I've browsed and read about this for hours but am still really confused as to why some methods work and some don't.

Thanks in advance

**Update**: Turns out I made some wrong assumptions on what Node's root object is in a given file or function call. Wasn't really aware of the module wrapper.

Comment: In the const defination it is not valid object you are missing , after filename. Could you check that is not the problem or is it just typo in your question.

Comment: Simple rule.  NEVER use `=>` to define methods on an object.  It will give you the lexical `this`, not the object `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This doc makes me think that the arrow function should inherit the this of the scope it's being called, which is readSave, which means this should be global.

No the `this` of the arrow function is determined at the time the arrow function is created:

> [...] No matter what, foo's `this` is set to what it was when **it was created** (in the example above, the global object). The same applies to arrow functions created **inside other functions**: their `this` **remains that of the enclosing lexical context** [...].

So `this` in the arrow function refers to what `this` is here:

```
console.dir(this) // <----  refers to `exports`
const folders = {
    category1: {
        fileName: 'default'
        path : '/path',
        subpath : () => `/subpath/${this.fileName}${this.uniqueId}`
    }
}
```

And the `this` for those two code block refer to the same object for this exact same reason:

```
console.dir(this) // the `this` in the arrow function below is the same as here
                  // and `this` refers to `exports`
const readSave3 = () => {
    this.fileName = 'filename'; 
    this.uniqueId = 1029;

    // ...
}

readSave3()
```

```
function readSave() {
   // ...
}

this.fileName = 'filename'; 
this.uniqueId = 1029;

readSave()
```

On load the content of a node file is wrapped into: ([The module wrapper](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper))

```
(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
   /*... filecontent ... */
})
```

That function is then called passing the corresponding values as arguments and that function is called *on* the object passed as `exports` to the function [What is the root object in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770299/meaning-of-this-in-node-js-modules-and-functions).

So for `/subpath/${this.fileName}${this.uniqueId}` the `this` refers to `exports` the same is with `readSave3` and your last code. For your `readSave` (the first one) the `this` refers to the global object.

So for node your code would look like this:

```
var moduleSetup = function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  // here `this` is exports 

  const folders = {
    category1: {
      fileName: 'default',
      path: '/path',
      // `this`referes to exports due to arrow function
      subpath: () => `/subpath/${this.fileName}${this.uniqueId}`
    }
  }


  function readSave1() {
    // here `this` refers to `global` because `readSave1` is not called on an object

    //suppose readFileSync would return a string 'filename' and an int 1029

    this.fileName = 'filename';
    this.uniqueId = 1029;

    let filePath = folders.category1.path + folders.category1.subpath();

    // I'd go on to write stuff to that file but for now let's just return
    return filePath;
  }

  readSave1()


  function readSave2() {
    let filePath = folders.category1.path + folders.category1.subpath();
    return filePath;
  }

  // `this` refers to `exports`
  this.fileName = 'filename';
  this.uniqueId = 1029;

  readSave2()


  const readSave3 = () => {
    // `this` refers to `exports` due to arrow function
    this.fileName = 'filename';
    this.uniqueId = 1029;

    let filePath = folders.category1.path + folders.category1.subpath();
    return filePath;
  }
  readSave3()
}

// and that's roughly how node would invoce that function:
var module = {
  exports: {}
}

moduleSetup.call(module.exports, // moduleSetup called on module.exports
                 // with these arguments:
                 module.exports, require, module, theFileName, theDirname)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the "when created" part. After some testing now I get it why options 2 and 3 work. However for the first option, where I set `this.fileName` inside readSave, I still need to study a bit. It seems straightforward on a browser, but on node there's also the global and the exports objects... Anyway the locus of the question now has shifted to how `this` and scope in general is inherited by a regular function. I should probably write a separate question.

Comment: @dalmo3 update my answer to contain this information

Comment: That wraps it up, marking it as solution. Just one thing, your comment under `readSave3`... `//this refers [to what?] due to arrow function`. I'm guessing `exports`.

Comment: @dalmo3 yes `exports` was missing there.

Answer (score 0):

`this` always point the current context. 
when the arrow function going to execute `this` change to its current context which is in your case is the arrow function. so the `this` inside the arrow function and outside of the arrow functions are not same they are in different context `this`

Comment: `[...]change to its current context which is in your case is the arrow function[...]` that does not make to much sense.