# this returns empty object when running a js file in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

when i try to reassign module.exports , `this` still points to an empty object

```js
module.exports  = {a:4}
console.log(this) // {}
```

however, when I add a new property to `module.exports` , `this` points to an object with the new property.

```js
module.exports.a = 4
console.log(this) // {a:4}
```

why do i not get the same result in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/22771432/7878410

When JavaScript files are required as Node modules, the Node engine runs the module code inside of a wrapper function. That module-wrapping function is invoked with `this` set to `module.exports`.

Hence, `module.exports` and `this` are pointing to the same object which is `{}` when you do the following,

```js
module.exports  = {a:4}
console.log(this) // {}
```

`module.exports` starts to point to a new object which is `{a:4}` whereas `this` still points to the previous object which is `{}`.

But, when you do the following,

```js
module.exports.a = 4
console.log(this) // {a:4}
```

You end up updating the object to which `module.exports` as well as `this` are pointing. Hence, `this` returns `{a:4}`

Answer (score 1):

By default in a module, `this` points to the original `exports` object that the module system creates when it sets up your module.  When you do:

```
module.exports = {a: 4}
```

You replace the existing `exports` property on the `module` object with a new and separate one.  But, `this` still points at the original, empty `exports` object.  So, when you do:

```
console.log(this);
```

after creating a new `exports` object, `this` is still pointing at the original `exports` object which you never modified.  So, it still shows that object as being empty.

If, after reassigning the exports property with a new object like you did above, you then did this:

```
console.log(module.exports === this);            // false
```

You will see that `this` does not point at the new `exports` object you assigned as a property on the `module` object.

---

On the other hand, when you do this:

```
module.exports.a = 4
```

You are not replacing the existing `exports` object.  Instead, you're just adding a property to the existing object, so the object you modified is the original `exports` object that `this` still points to.