# Adding properties to global object in JS

Tags: javascript, this, global-object

why adding a property to globalThis inside a function doesn't work?

```js
let foo = function(){
    this.name='Global Elite'
}
foo()
console.log(this.name) // undefined
```

This gets more confusing because if I use the arrow function instead the function keyword it can add the name property to global object.

```
let foo = ()=>{
    this.name='Global Elite'
}
foo()
console.log(this.name) // Global Elite
```

Edit: I ran the above code in node js.

Comment: cannot reproduce, also note, that this would throw in strict mode.

Comment: Edited your post to actually run your script. It doesn't behave as you described. Please update the example.

Comment: Can reproduce when ran on Node.js.

Comment: This is not really a duplicate unless we understand what the OP is asking, since the behavior they describe seems impossible.

Comment: like @Ivar posted, [understanding This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) `Arrow functions don’t have their own this […] binding. Instead, [this identifier is] resolved in the lexical scope like any other variable. That means that inside an arrow function, this [refers] to the [value of this] in the environment the arrow function is defined in (i.e. “outside” the arrow function).`

Comment: @knicholas Thanks, I understood that the arrow function have their own 'this', so its resolved in the lexical scope. But but i don't understand why this outside any function refers to an empty object where as in the node interpreter 'this' refers to the global object.

Comment: @HimanshuBharti I believe that is because node uses modules and `The GetThisBinding concrete method of a module Environment Record […] [does this]:

Return undefined.`

Comment: The "why" can be answered with "because the specifications says so". ASDFGerte posted a link earlier pointing to [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770299/meaning-of-this-in-node-js-modules-and-functions), which basically states your findings as facts.