# Why is function wrapper called with module.exports instead of module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

Snipper from source code

[image: 1]
Like the answer below says:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22771432
When JavaScript files are `require()`d as Node modules, the Node engine runs the module code inside of a wrapper function. That module-wrapping function is invoked with a `this` set to `module.exports`

This is what I don't understand, why calling it `module.exports` rather than just `module`?
The wrapped function is passed `module.exports` as `this` keyword but why don't we just pass  `module`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the loader code yourself [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/e3bf5e1ac80f45c67ad55823033dc7ff485c90ec/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L1033).  Where the `this` value for a module is set is actually [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/e3bf5e1ac80f45c67ad55823033dc7ff485c90ec/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L1119).

I can't say why they decided it should be the `exports` object rather than `module` object.  Perhaps because that's what they expect you to assign to and it's certainly more common to reference `exports` than it is `module`.

Both the `module` object and the `exports` objects are passed as an argument to the wrapper and are in scope for your code so you can reference either one without using `this` and, in my opinion, it makes for clearer code to use `module` or `module.exports` directly rather than using `this`.

---

Here's a copy of the relevant code from the above link. The `this` value is set in the `ReflectApply()` call near the bottom of this block in the variable named `thisValue`.

```
// Run the file contents in the correct scope or sandbox. Expose
// the correct helper variables (require, module, exports) to
// the file.
// Returns exception, if any.
Module.prototype._compile = function(content, filename) {
  let moduleURL;
  let redirects;
  if (policy?.manifest) {
    moduleURL = pathToFileURL(filename);
    redirects = policy.manifest.getDependencyMapper(moduleURL);
    policy.manifest.assertIntegrity(moduleURL, content);
  }

  maybeCacheSourceMap(filename, content, this);
  const compiledWrapper = wrapSafe(filename, content, this);

  let inspectorWrapper = null;
  if (getOptionValue('--inspect-brk') && process._eval == null) {
    if (!resolvedArgv) {
      // We enter the repl if we're not given a filename argument.
      if (process.argv[1]) {
        try {
          resolvedArgv = Module._resolveFilename(process.argv[1], null, false);
        } catch {
          // We only expect this codepath to be reached in the case of a
          // preloaded module (it will fail earlier with the main entry)
          assert(ArrayIsArray(getOptionValue('--require')));
        }
      } else {
        resolvedArgv = 'repl';
      }
    }

    // Set breakpoint on module start
    if (resolvedArgv && !hasPausedEntry && filename === resolvedArgv) {
      hasPausedEntry = true;
      inspectorWrapper = internalBinding('inspector').callAndPauseOnStart;
    }
  }
  const dirname = path.dirname(filename);
  const require = makeRequireFunction(this, redirects);
  let result;
  const exports = this.exports;
  const thisValue = exports;
  const module = this;
  if (requireDepth === 0) statCache = new SafeMap();
  if (inspectorWrapper) {
    result = inspectorWrapper(compiledWrapper, thisValue, exports,
                              require, module, filename, dirname);
  } else {
    result = ReflectApply(compiledWrapper, thisValue,
                          [exports, require, module, filename, dirname]);
  }
  hasLoadedAnyUserCJSModule = true;
  if (requireDepth === 0) statCache = null;
  return result;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I haven taken a look at all the relevant code.
Your " Perhaps because that's what they expect you to assign to and it's certainly more common to reference exports than it is module. " response is what I really wanted to dig into, for now I am gonna assume this was the reason behind module.exports and not just module.

Comment: oh, yeah i tried to upvote and it didn't let me
Thanks for letting me know :)