# what is defference between console.log(this) in nodejs and console.log(this) in browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables, this, window-object

When I log (this) in the browser I get window Object, But when I log (this) in node.js I got {}.
I road global object in node js is same window object in browser, What is precisely the deference between this and global Object in Node.js?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: This is a massive topic, and I would recommend referring to the official documentation, which is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is capable of printing objects without the need to convert them into strings in the console log, while i am guessing in the browser that is not possible. "{}" is an empty object  in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to me seems to be, in both examples `this` is the global object for the JavaScript runtime.

- In the browser, `this` is the Browser Object Model

  - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp
  - *"All global JavaScript objects, functions, and variables automatically become members of the window object."*
  - It is a collection of properties and methods that contain information about the browser and computer screen.
  - Even the document object (of the HTML DOM) is a property of the window object.
- The difference is in the top-level code in a Node module, `this` is equivalent to `module.exports`. That's the empty object you see.

  - [Meaning of "this" in node.js modules and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770299/meaning-of-this-in-node-js-modules-and-functions))
  - you would need a library called `jsdom` in Node.js to get access to the APIs used in a browser DOM https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom